# Momentum conservation on 2 buggies

Tags: homework-and-exercises, momentum, conservation-laws

**Question**
[image]

**Attempt** 
I tried taking a system in which there was visibly no external force and applied momentum conservation. But my answer came wrong. Where did I go wrong? Please help. 
[image]

I am in high school so I dont know much advanced concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial condition is correct. The buggy without the man would have $p = M \cdot v_1$ and the man $p = m \cdot v_1$. Now for the second buggy the same with $v_2$. For the first buggy to completely stop moving after the jump, its momentum would need to be $0$ but due to conservation of momentum it is also equal to the sum of the momentum of the second man and the first buggy before the jump: $0 = m \cdot v_2 + M \cdot v_1$. The second buggy now moves at speed $v$ so: $p_{f,\ buggy\ 2} = (m + M) \cdot v = m \cdot v_1 + M \cdot v_2$ also due to conservation of momentum. We have 2 equations and 2 variables so this is solvable!

Isolate $v_1$ from the first equation: $v_1 = \frac{-m\cdot v_2}{M}$. We fill it in in the second equation: $(m+M) \cdot v = m \cdot \frac{-m\cdot v_2}{M} + M \cdot v_2$ from which we get: $v_2\cdot (\frac{-m^2}{M} + M) = (m+M) \cdot v$ or $v_2 = \frac{(m+M) \cdot v}{\frac{-m^2}{M} + M} = \frac{(m+M) \cdot v\cdot M}{M^2-m^2} = \frac{v \cdot M}{M-m}$. Filling into the formula for $v_1$: $v_1 = \frac{-m\cdot v_2}{M} = \frac{-v\cdot m}{M-m}$, the minus sign indicates them moving in opposite directions. Assuming the men weigh less than a buggy, the first buggy moves slower than the second buggy in the beginning. You can also see that $v < v_2$ which is also expected.

Comment: But I dont understand why considering the first man and first buggy as a system fails to give answer.

Comment: The system you are considering does not have conserved momentum. The man and buggy exchange momentum with the other man and buggy, and arrive at a new momentum. Only the total momentum in the entire exercise is conserved. To see this, if you agree with my solution, you can calculate it before and after the jump: $p_{before} = (m + M)\cdot v_1 = -\frac{M+m}{M-m}v\cdot m$ while $p_{after} = -m\cdot v + M\cdot 0 = -m\cdot v$. You can see that for your system, $p_{before} > p_{after}$ and the opposite will be true for the second buggy and man. Thus: the total momentum is still conserved.

Comment: The man jumping over can be interpreted as an amount of momentum jumping over from one system to the other. Just like when a bowling ball hits a bowling pin, after the hit the ball goes a little bit slower and the pin gains speed. The momentum is transferred. Only when considering the system pin + ball it is conserved. Is my solution what you were supposed to get?